# How to make a struct accept one of two types as an argument?

Tags: go, struct, interface

I have a struct `DbConnector` which I want to use as a proxy to communicate with a database.

This struct has method `Init(db *sql.DB)`.

Depending on conditions, I want to be able to initialise it with another struct, like `DummyDatabaseConnection` for testing.

How do I define the signature of `Init()` so that it accepts either `*sql.DB` or `*DummyDatabaseConnection`?

Comment: Use interface. And `*sql.DB` and `*DummyDatabaseConnection` both need to implement that interface

Comment: [Interfaces are covered in the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an Interface with some methods you need to call for `*sql.DB` & `*DummyDatabaseConnection`

```
type DBInterface interface {
    Ping() error
    Close() error
    // Some other Methods that you need
}
```

Now your DummyDatabaseConnection should satisfy your DBInterface.

```
type DummyDatabaseConnection struct {
}

func(d *DummyDatabaseConnection) Ping()error {
    return nil
}


func(d *DummyDatabaseConnection) Close()error {
    return nil
}
```

Use your Interface as argument

```
func (d *DbConnector) Init(db DBInterface) {
    db.Ping()
    db.Close()
}
```

Call with which one you need.

```
    dbConnector := &DbConnector{}

    // Call with *sql.DB
    db := &sql.DB{}
    dbConnector.Init(db)

    // Call with *DummyDatabaseConnection
    db := &DummyDatabaseConnection{}
    dbConnector.Init(db)
```

From your `Init(db DBInterface)` method, you only can call methods those are in *DBInterface* interface

Check [this post](https://medium.com/golangspec/interfaces-in-go-part-i-4ae53a97479c)

Hope this will help